# how to call an API from server side in NextJs app on button click

Tags: reactjs, next.js13

I am using NextJS application and want to call an API on button click, but this should be done through server. I am not able to find any solid results on internet which clearly demonstrate this procedure.

I have tried to make a function "get user by id" in a page under `> src > pages > api > users > [id].tsx` and calling this function from button click but this is again the API call on client side. but I want to call API to get user by id from server and too on onclick of button

Answer (score 0):

> but I want to call API to get user by id from server and too on onclick of button

What do you mean exactly by calling it from the server? Do you intend to hide some sensitive information from spilling into the client side?

Your setup seems fine.
You have defined an API route which will be called when you call the `/api/users/:id` using axios or fetch. If you want to ensure unauthenticated users can't retrieve other users' information, you can add an auth layer before returning the response from the API.

PS. Next.js API routes are run on server side so whatever code is written inside an API route is not delivered to the clients.

Do let me know if that makes sense and I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: so is this enough in `/api/users/:id`?

```export default function gatewayHandler(idd: string) {
    const fetchData = async () => {
        const session = await getSession();
        const id = parseInt(idd as string, 10);
        const prvtInstance = axios.create({
            baseURL: sensitiveUrl,
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${session?.accessToken}` },
        });

        const resp = await prvtInstance.get(`orgs/${id}`);
        console.log('resp', resp);
        return resp;
    };
    fetchData();
}
```

Comment: because I tried `const res = await fetch(
      `/api/gateway/${72}`
    );` and it returns 404

Comment: From the code it seems you're trying to call the getSession from next-auth to get the user session which you're then passing into the protected API call from axios. Since the getSession can only be called from client side, you don't an API route for this provided that the sensitive URL you're referring to is another backend API.